# Thumbnail appearing small, not reflecting what is set in elementor

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images, thumbnails

I have a strange issue that is occurring on my site and after plenty of googling I have not been able to find the answer hence my post here.

The first screenshot is when I go to edit the page within Elementor - it looks how I intend it to look, however, the second image is of my site and how it looks and there is a huge difference in the size of the images. I have 2 pages where I can see this happening so I'm not sure if there's a "parent" setting somewhere that is adjusting the images to be smaller than intended? Apologies if this is a really simple issue, I have tried looking with no joy.

I am using Hello Elementor theme.

Edit: This did work at one point, however I needed to amend the permalink for products, and some other changes.

EDIT 2! I don't seem to get this problem with the "product grid" from elementor, only with the "products" widget.

Many Thanks in Advance
Andy
[image: elementor display]

[image: website display]